# ingest CSV files from an external server to HDFS cluster using flume

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, flume

I need your help

I'am new in the Apache Flume. We have a multi node cluster, and we want to ingest csv files from an external server to HDFS using flume. the probleme is I dont know exactelly where to install flume.

-Do I need to install it on an edge node?

-If so, do I have to add that node to my hadoop cluster?

-Do any  one have an idea how to configure flume agent to write the csv files into HDFS in my case?

Comment: What reasons do you think Flume is the solution to your problem?

Comment: Actually, I did some search on the internet and I found that it's possible to load large files into hdfs using Flume (spool directory). do you have other suggestion?

Comment: You're correct, but I was curious since there's other ways to load the data. So, you know about the spooling directory, so is anything working? Any errors?

Comment: concerning I have tested it on a local directory and a local HDFS sink, it worked fine 
but now, I want to get files from an external server to my HDFS cluster and i don't know exactly where to configure my flume agent

Comment: Have you installed the flume agent on the remote machine? And setup the hdfs sink path to the correct `hdfs://remote.ip/path` ?